# Remove Element from JDOM document using removeContent()

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Given the following scenario, where the xml, Geography.xml looks like -

```
<Geography xmlns:ns="some valid namespace">
    <Country>
        <Region>
            <State>
                <City>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Population></Population>
                </City>
            </State>
            </Region>
        </Country>
    </Geography>
```

and the following sample java code -

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Geography.xml");
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = saxBuilder.build(is);

XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/*/Country/Region/State/City");
Element el = (Element) xpath.selectSingleNode(doc);
boolean b = doc.removeContent(el);
```

The `removeContent()` method doesn't remove the Element `City` from the content list of the `doc`. The value of b is `false`
I don't understand why is it not removing the Element, I even tried to delete the `Name` & `Population` elements from the xml just to see if that was the issue but apparently its not.
Another way I tried, I don't know why I know its not essentially different, still just for the sake, was to use `Parent` -

```
Parent p = el.getParent();
boolean s = p.removeContent(new Element("City"));
```

What might the problem? and a possible solution? and if anyone can share the real behaviour of the method `removeContent()`, I suspect it has to do with the parent-child relationship.

Comment: What is `res`? Another document?

Comment: @Thomas - Oops!, very sorry typo. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, `removeContent(Content child)` removes child if child belongs to the parents immediate children, which it does not in your case. Use `el.detach()`instead.

Comment: @dogbane Both these solutions seem to work and now I understand why it wasn't working earlier. Thanks a lot. I have to choose one solution so I might just go with this one, unless you guys think otherwise for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove the `City` element, get its parent and call `removeContent`:

```
    XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/*/Country/Region/State/City");
    Element el = (Element) xpath.selectSingleNode(doc);
    el.getParent().removeContent(el);
```

The reason why `doc.removeContent(el)` does not work is because `el` is not a child of `doc`.

Check the [javadocs](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Document.html#removeContent%28%29) for details. There are a number of overloaded `removeContent` methods there.

Comment: `el.detach()` does `el.getParent().removeContent(el);` and is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This way works keeping in mind that .getParent() returns a Parent object instead of an Element object, and the detach() method which eliminates the actual node, must be called from an Element.

Instead do:

```
el.getParentElement().detach();
```

This will remove the parent element with all it's children !